# EF is not cascade deleting

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

The problem is i cannot perform cascade deletion using only EF codefirst conventions. They, in particular, say: ["If a foreign key on the dependent entity is not nullable, then Code First sets cascade delete on the relationship"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)

I have parent and child entities:

```
[Table("AssociationPages")]
public class AssociationPage
{
    [Column("AssociationPageID"), Required, Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("AssociationSetting")]
    public int AssociationId { get; set; }
    public virtual AssociationSetting AssociationSetting { get; set; }
}

[Table("AssociationSetting")]
public class AssociationSetting
{
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int AssociationId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssociationPage> Pages { get; set; }

}
```

My AssociationPages table in MS SQL Server looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AssociationPages](
    [AssociationPageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AssociationId] [int] NOT NULL,
...
)
```

and a FK (but it shouldnt matter as EF has its own conventions):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AssociationPages]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ChamberPages_Chambers] FOREIGN KEY([AssociationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AssociationSetting] ([AssociationId])
GO
```

So i have non-nullable FK everywhere but once i try to delete parent AssociationSetting row then getting the "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint FK_ChamberPages_Chambers. The conflict occurred in database ..., table dbo.AssociationPages, column AssociationId message". I know i can set constraints inside database or with EF fluent API but why *this* is not working?
Thanks for your ideas!

**update**
WillCascadeOnDelete() doesnt work as well :(

Comment: For what it's worth, the cascade delete occurs with your code on my machine, using VS2012, EF4, and letting the DB be generated automatically by codefirst. Are you deleting in a "normal" way, e.g., `db.AssociationSettings.Remove(settings)`?

Comment: @MykWillis yes, i remove it like this. My DB was not generated from EF, i made it earlier and the database's FK is not cascade (sic!). I hoped that EF can maintain cascade deletion independently of database level relationships. Am i mistaking? PS: i am using EF5, VS2012, SQL2012Express

Answer (score 0):

It may be that Code First is not setting up the cascade since you are not following the naming conventions.

Try this:

```
public class AssociationPage
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int AssociationSettingId { get; set; }

  public virtual AssociationSetting AssociationSetting { get; set; }
}

public class AssociationSetting
{

  public int Id { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<AssociationPage> Pages { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Shiraz, what's the meaning of this?

Comment: This is your code rewritten to use conventions instead of Attributes

Comment: it didn't help, unfortunatey

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in investigation purposes i created a simpliest parent-child tables, put two rows - one per table, created FK relationship as "No Action" on cascade delete and wrote EF Code First entities.
Then I set up FK relationship variuos ways - via column attributes, Fluent API, explicitly specifying WillDeleteOnCascade() method or alltogether but had no luck trying to delete parent row. The only way I achieved this when retrieved both parent and child records prior to removing. At this point SQL profiler shown that rows being deleted one by one both for parent and children tables.
Summarizing the above I suppose the cascading in EF *Code First* means the setting constraints on the database being created by EF. I might be missing something thu.